# How can I Change Password of Cisco (C3560-IPBASEK9-M) Switch with Command Line?

Tags: cisco, switch, password, putty

I can make remote (ssh) connection to my Cisco (C3560-IPBASEK9-M) switch on putty and I can log in with username and password.
How can I change password -that I use when I log in- on this command line? ( I'm very beginner, I made some search but couldn't find it)

Comment: What Cisco device is this? And what password would you like to change? Given the right device, there would be multiple passwords to change.

Comment: The device is C3560-IPBASEK9-M. Password that I use when I log in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to solve this simply by:

- Log in with your existing credentials
- Enter enable mode `en`
- Enter config mode `conf t`
- Using the following command to set the given password for the user: `username MYUSER privilege 15 password MYPASSWORD`

Input the above command with the username you want to add or change.

I reccomend adding a new user instead of trying to edit the old if you have no easy way to physically access the switch in case you need to recover the password (if editing is unsuccessful). This will give you the option of testing the new credentials, and still have access via the old user if needed.

If it's complaining about the password not being encrypted, you could enter the following command instead: `username MYUSER privilege 15 password 0 MYPASSWORD`
This should write the password in clear-text to your config file. If that is the case, you can also run `service password-encryption` to make the system encrypt them for you.

Double check your running-config when done, that password(s) are encrypted and everything is in order - and remember to save the config with `wr` or `copy running-config startup-config`